# Importing Libraries to an Android project

Tags: android, import, libraries

I have imported a project from a book on Android development and I am currently getting warnings icons appearing next to a number of imports at the start of my project. When I hover over the warning icon the message that appears is as follows...

"The import java.io.IOException is never used"

I received these warning before on another project and when I imported a the necessary library the warning icons disappeared. My problem is that I do not know which library to import to resolve the warning symbol next to the following statements in my .java file...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

Comment: Doesn't the warning speak for itself? You're importing stuff that you're not using. Since this is a project from a book it's kind of weird though. You _"resolve"_ this by removing the import.

Comment: try hitting cltr+shift+o and all the required packages will be imported and unnecessary (never used imports) will be removed

Comment: Could you explain why these imports appeared there in the first place? I mean why would they be included in a pre-built project if there were only to be removed by the end user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Eclipse. Go to **Source -> Organize Imports**. The unnecessary imports should automatically be removed and only the ones really needed should remain.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a problem and you don''t need to import any library to fix this.

All you need to do is "organize imports"

Option 1: right click in the editor ->Source->Organize Imports

Option 2: press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+o

Answer (score 0):

"The import java.io.IOException is never used"
This warning means that you have imported a class `java.io.IOException` that you are not using in your code. This is not a compiling error so you don't have to fix it in order to run correctly your project.

Anyway if you wanna make the warning vanish there are many ways.The fastest one is to just eliminate this line. If you are using Eclipse and you have many warnings like this then the fastest fix is to put the **mouse cursor over the yellow underlined text** and **wait** the open of the **quick-fix panel** of Eclipse. In this panel you can chose both ***"remove unused import"*** or ***"Organize import"***. Both this system will remove all your unused import. There is also a third option: *"@Suppress warnings"*. In this case you shouldn't use this option because it will only hide the warning not solving the problem.

Eclipse quick-fix is a powerful feature, using it will fast your code writing a lot so you should start practice it ^^

This kind of error are quiet often in project because many programmers doesn't care a lot for the "unused import warnings" and through the code change they forget to remove useless import